# Argument Requirement Error in URDF Tutorial Display Launch

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please help me regarding below error:-

[/opt/ros/kinetic/share/urdf_tutorial/launch/display.launch] requires the 'model' arg to be set
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.

regards
saurabh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401754/%5B/opt/ros/kinetic/share/urdf_tutorial/launch/display.launch%5D-requires-the-%27model%27-arg-to-be-set-the-traceback-for-the-exception-was-written-to-the-log-file/) by [saurabh jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/106664/saurabh-jha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch), you'll see that it launches `display.launch` by using:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

You need to add the argument `model` to tell the launch file which model to use, as you can see in the example above (and the tutorial). You haven't added the argument.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saurabh jha](https://answers.ros.org/users/106664/saurabh-jha/) on 2022-06-03**:
thank you problem resolve

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-06-03**:
Please mark this answer as correct so others know it's been resolved.